# Где скачать JDK 8 для Windows 7 32bit?

Tags: java

Всем добрый вечер, я не смог найти где скачать JDK 8 для семерки 32bit. Вот тут http://free-software.com.ua/programming/jdk/download/ можно?  Первая ссылка без указания бит, а вторая с указанием 64 бит  мне по первой ссылке качать?

Comment: Качайте с официального сайта: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html (гуглится запросом "jdk download" в гугле, надо искать ссылку на oracle.com)

Comment: @yeputons, в том и дело, у них на сайте нет для 32bit

Comment: на официальном сайте есть, называется "x86".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java JDK 32 битная система обозначена как x86. Так что вам нужно будет скачать для x86. А если у вас будет возможность, ставьте 64 битную систему Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Скачать можно прямо с официального сайта:
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-windows-i586.exe